# How Cassandra can provide optimized solution for a Overlapping range check

Tags: cql, cassandra-2.0

In my input I have a key , a lower bound of range R1, a upper bound of range R1. and some data.I have to insert this data only after getting ensured that my input range  R1 should not overlap any other present ranges already present in cassandra.

So with before each insert i have to fire a select query

```
   key | lowerbound | upperbound | data
------+------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
1024 | 1000 | 1100 | <blob>
1024 | 1500 | 1900 | <blob> 
1024 | 2000 | 2900 | <blob> 
1024 | 3000 | 3900 | <blob> 
1024 | 4000 | 4500 | <blob> 

Case1 Given Range R(S,E)=(1,999)
This is a positive case hence system should Insert the data   

Case2:  Given Range R(S,E)=(1001,1010)
this is a Negative case hence system should discard the data
```

***I have a solution with one  Range query and one programmatic check solution***

**please let me know whether this kind of problem statement have solution in Cassandra if yes can it be optimized to get a better performance**

Comment: and am open for any suggestion which involve schema change. pleas help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a better solution for your problem: this is the only way. Possibly in future Lightweight Transactions might help also for these situations but now the only solution you have is to read before writing. One more consideration: ensure to avoid double insertion in concurrency situation (if this can happen in your application).

Cheers,
Carlo

Comment: Hi @Carlo thanks for the suggestion.Did you mean entering same key twice by "double insertion"?

Comment: Yes, I mean entering same key twice!

Comment: Calro is there any way i can speed up the select query. I have read caching will help. do you have any idea?

Comment: Nothing in particular comes into my mind except rows-caching, but you already found it. If using DSE (commercial distribution) you could gain advantage from in-memory tables

Comment: thanks for the information. I will check on row caching. If you have some good links for row caching please share it. And for preventing double insertion (as you have suggested) i am using Lightweight transaction).

Comment: Here is a good reading concerning row-caching: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/row-caching-in-cassandra-2-1  -- as far as Lightweight transactions, if you can avoid them via-application (using HazelCast/ZooKeeper or whatever) you could improve performance.